# Activating Windows Server 2012 R2 Evaluation version to Retail version

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, licensing

I have downloaded and installed the Windows Server 2012 R2 evaluation version from Microsoft's Evaluation Center website. We decided to go ahead and activate it to the full version. We bought a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard DVD and attempted to use the Key provided with the DVD following the method described here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574204.aspx

Yes, I did notice the mistake in the instructions and instead of finding out my version, I used "DISM /online /Get-TargetEditions" command to be able to get the correct parameter for the version of Windows Server I intend to upgrade to. The result was "ServerStandard".

So now, the new command is "DISM /online /Set-Edition:ServerStandard /ProductKey: /AcceptEula". I get the error the product key could not be validated. Check that the specified product key is valid and that it matches the target edition.

Does this mean that I won't be able to use the key from the DVD? Are they not the same edition? If they are, how do I go about activating the server? If the key can't be used, does this mean I will have to make a reinstall using the DVD?

Excuse me if this sounds like a question that can be answered through a simple Google search, but believe me, there is very little documentation, and that's why I'm turning to you guys.

Comment: What happened when you started over and followed the directions as they were given?

Comment: Tried that first. Same error. @Michael

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried activating it with the slmgr command?

```
slmgr /ipk <key>
```

and then

```
slmgr /ato
```

Comment: Ok I tried it after hours. After the first command, I received a message saying the product key is invalid. Then after the second command, I received a message saying that the product activation was successful. But, after reboot, I still have the desktop saying I'm still in evaluation mode. Also, do I need to include the dashes in the product key, or just type all the characters together?

Comment: Very strange. And you're sure that your key is for the right version? (Datacenter,Standard)

Yes the key can/should contain the dashes: slmgr /ipk XXXX-XXXX-XXX...

Comment: And I found my mistake. I'm running Windows Server 2012 (non R2!), and the DVD I bought is R2... geez... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a Server 2012 R2 product key to activate Server 2012, and vice versa.

Comment: I thought it was possible to get an R2 license with downgrade rights?

Comment: @Colyn1337 What are you downgrading from? Where did you hide your time machine?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/OEM/en/licensing/sblicensing/Pages/downgrade_rights.aspx#fbid=aN-x668Fnfj

Comment: @Colyn1337 Not sure why you posted that, since it only confirms what I said above. You may have downgrade rights, but you still have to use a different product key.

Comment: Does it?  "Perform the downgrade process to the eligible downgrade product using the media/key from a genuine, previously licensed OEM or retail product."

Comment: @Colyn1337 Exactly!

Comment: The way I read your answer sounds like you're negating that statement.

Comment: @Colyn1337 Obviously that's not the case. Did you not have enough coffee this morning? :)

Comment: You can downgrade from  2012 R2 to 2012.  You're answer expressly states you can't do that, which is wrong per the link I provided.

Comment: @Colyn1337 No, that is _not_ what I said. You are perfectly capable of downgrading. But as both I and that link stated, you have to use the appropriate product key.

Comment: The instructions in the link I provided say to use the key for the previous version.

Comment: @Colyn1337 And that's _also_ what I said!

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://blogs.technet.com/b/licensing/archive/2013/02/07/downgrade-rights-explained.aspx