# Upgrading Windows Server 2012 from evaluation to standard edition

Tags: windows-server-2012, upgrade

So I have a server running Windows Server 2012 that I want to upgrade from the evaluation version, to full. Going through the process of using Powershell to find the current and target editions, and then applying

```
DISM /online /Set-Edition:<edition ID> /ProductKey:XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX /AcceptEula,
```

to update, I continually get the error that my product key is wrong. I am not quite sure why this is happening because I did indeed buy the correct key. Any ideas as to what is wrong?

Comment: You cannot covert domain controller, see https://technet.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/jj574204.aspx

Comment: I know that. I have removed Active Directory from my server

Comment: Make sure that the installed evaluation edition and version match exactly with the purchased product keys, see http://serverfault.com/a/613814/229754

Comment: Have made sure of that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slmgr /ipk  as per https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn502540.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 - note this would be a comment not necessarily a fix but I don't have the reputation to make comments , I am just a Microsoft employee